# By reference vs by value java

Tags: java, reference, state

I am trying to solve the famous 8-puzzle, where a 3*3 square is filled with 1 empty slot and 8 numbers, solving is to return it to the original state.

to do this, I have a "state" of arraylist which stores the numbers 0~9, representing the puzzle.

the solution involves spawning multitudes of possible move-states, meaning I save every legal move made and the resulting puzzle. This is done using the below methods, but my swapAndStore will not edit the original passed array every pass. instead, when called upon in the genSuccessors() below that, it will work fine for the first if condition, then apply the next if condition on the result of the first if. I thought I fixed the issue by making a new puzzlestate called "oldBoard" to save the original input puzzle for future reference, but this did not work either. A friend told me this might have to do with the reference issue, which I cannot grasp well. I understand that when x=0, y=1, java will not do a swap(x,y) so that x = 1, y=0, but cannot see how this applies here.
suggestions?

```
   private void swapAndStore(int d1, int d2, ArrayList<State> s)
{
    //int[] cpy = copyBoard(curBoard);
    int[] cpy = new int [curBoard.length];
    System.arraycopy(curBoard,0,cpy,0,curBoard.length);
    int[] oldBoard = new int [curBoard.length];
    System.arraycopy(curBoard,0,oldBoard,0,curBoard.length);
    int temp = cpy[d1];
    cpy[d1] = cpy[d2];
    cpy[d2] = temp;
    s.add((new State(cpy)));
    curBoard = oldBoard;
    System.out.println("swapandstore storing" );
    s.get(s.size()-1).printState();

}

public ArrayList<State> genSuccessors()
{
    ArrayList<State> successors = new ArrayList<State>();
    int hole = getHole();

    // try to generate a state by sliding a tile leftwise into the hole
    // if we CAN slide into the hole
    if (hole != 0 && hole != 3 && hole != 6)
    {
        /*
         * we can slide leftwise into the hole, so generate a new state for
         * this condition and throw it into successors
         */;
        System.out.println("left");
        swapAndStore(hole - 1, hole, successors);
    }

    // try to generate a state by sliding a tile topwise into the hole
    if (hole != 6 && hole != 7 && hole != 8)
    {
        System.out.println("top");
        swapAndStore(hole + 3, hole, successors);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is pass by value - *always*.

Primitives are passed by value; object references are passed by value.

This means that you cannot alter the value of the reference.  But in the case of objects, you can alter their state - if they're mutable.

So you can do this:

```
package cruft;

import java.io.PrintStream;

/**
 * ArraySwapDemo description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link
 * @since 12/3/12 9:48 PM
 */
public class ArraySwapDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(String.format("before: %s", arrayToString(args)));
        swapValues(args, 0, args.length-1);
        System.out.println(String.format("after : %s", arrayToString(args)));
    }

    // No checks for proper indexes, but you get the idea.
    private static void swapValues(String[] args, int i, int j) {
        String temp = args[i];
        args[i] = args[j];
        args[j] = temp;
    }

    public static String arrayToString(String [] array) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(1024);
        buffer.append('{');
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; ++i) {
           buffer.append(array[i]).append(',');
        }
        buffer.append(array[array.length-1]).append('}');
        return buffer.toString();
    }

}
```

If I run it with four strings on the command line - foo bar baz bat - I get this result:

```
java cruft.ArraySwapDemo foo bar baz bat
before: {foo,bar,baz,bat}
after : {bat,bar,baz,foo}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: u might wanna add : tl;dr; :)

Comment: @DarthVader is saying he has a reading comprehension problem :D

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, the logic in your swap and its application seems pretty much identical to mine. What's the difference?

Comment: I don't know; I couldn't really follow what your problem is.  I do know that it's possible to swap values in an array.  Perhaps you need some kind of recursion to generate a game tree.